# How to set db timeout in webpy?

Tags: python, web.py

How to set db timeout in **webpy**

And how you usually do when db timeout in **webpy** ?

Comment: see http://webpy.org/cookbook/sessions

Comment: I don`t use sessions . Only datebase operation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about a MySQL DB...

Mysql connector has connection_timeout parameter [1].

And web.py's MySQL class[2] uses **keywords in his definition, maybe you could use connection_timeout.

At least I've tried here and my connection works. I've just couldn't wait to see if it drops when time expires.

[1] - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/connector-python-connectargs.html

[2] - https://github.com/webpy/webpy/blob/master/web/db.py